# Javascript New Array Functionality

Tags: javascript, prototype

I came across the below code in one website and I am unable to understand the line commented as "DOUBT".
How is the function returning the repeated text by using "new Array(n + 1).join(this)" ?

```
if (!String.prototype.repeat) { 
  String.prototype.repeat = function(n) {
    return new Array(n + 1).join(this);    /* DOUBT */
  };
}
alert( "La".repeat(3) );

Output: LaLaLa
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you `join` an array of length `n` by an argument `str`, you'll create a new string by inserting `n - 1` items of `str`, such that one is between each array item. Eg:

```
const arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
arr.join(' ')
// results in
// foo bar baz
```

The `new Array(n + 1)` creates an array which has length `n + 1` but has no elements. These non-existent elements, when converted into a string by `.join`, result in the empty string.

The `this` inside `String.prototype.repeat` is the string the function is being called on. For example:

```
'foo'.repeat(
```

results in `String.prototype.repeat` being called with a `this` of `'foo'`.

So:

```
new Array(n + 1).join(this)
```

results in a new string containing `n` repetitions of `this`.

Another way of looking at it, if `'x'.repeat(2)` is called, the following array is constructed:

```
// [<empty>, <empty>, <empty>]
// insert 'x' between each element of the array:
// '' + 'x' + '' + 'x' + ''
// result: 'xx'
```

Comment: In other words joining `null` values `n` times with separator `foo`

Answer (score 0):

I am Tigran, and I can answer your question.

There is we polifying repeat method in String class:

```
 if (!String.prototype.repeat) { 
  String.prototype.repeat = function(n) {
     //some code
  }
}
```

There are this - a given string (in this example "La"):

```
return new Array(n + 1).join(this);
```

Let's discuss by "La" string, `"La".repeat(3)` there are `this` is "La" and n is 3.
`new Array(3 + 1)` -> `[empty × 4]`
`[,,,,].join('La')` -> `"LaLaLa"` (, -> empty) 
  join is method for converting array to string by given string.
If there are any questions, feel free to ask.